# Sequalize.js, max pubDate of model returning older entry instead of latest

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, restify

Okay, here it goes, am using node.js with sequalize.js as ORM for my application. there is an api endpoint called maxEntry which returns the latest entry sorted by "pubDate". However, the entry being returned from my app is not the latest one.

This is my database:

[image]

and this is what is being returned from my API:

[image]

This is my code:

```
//Entity Models
var Entry = sequelize.define('entry', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    pubDate: Sequelize.DATE,
    countryCode: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    type: Sequelize.STRING
});

var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.CORS());

server.get('/maxEntry', maxEntry);

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('API listening at %s', server.url);
});

function maxEntry(req, res, next) {
    Entry.sync().then(function () {
        Entry.findOne({
            where: {
                type: 'Warning'
            },
            order: [
              sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('pubDate'))
            ]
        }).then(function (entry) {
            res.send(entry);
            next();
        });
    });
}
```

Can you please help as to why it's not pulling the latest entry? Thank you very much!

Comment: okay forget it, am an idiot, order query is wrong, should be:             order: [
                ['pubDate', 'DESC'],
            ]

Answer (score 0):

okay forget it, am an idiot, order query is wrong, should be: order: [ ['pubDate', 'DESC'], ]